# Two Views, one Animation but there's a problem

Tags: java, android, animation, view

This is my code:

```
AlphaAnimation anim_fadeIn;
Button button, button2;
TextView t, e;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    t = findViewById(R.id.text_Splash_t);
    e = findViewById(R.id.text_Splash_e);

    button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button2 =  findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mAnimate();
        }
    });
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mAnimate2();
        }
    });

    anim_fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
    anim_fadeIn.setDuration(1000);
    anim_fadeIn.setFillAfter(true);



 private void mAnimate() {
            t.startAnimation(anim_fadeIn);
}



private void mAnimate2() {
            e.startAnimation(anim_fadeIn);
}
```

Scenario:

press button1 and text1 will animate (even if you  do it some times). Then pressing button2 will add the view somewhere so no matter if you press the button1 or 2, both Texts will animate

Scenario 2:

press button2 and text2 will animate (even if you  do it some times). Then pressing button1 will add the view somewhere so no matter if you press the button1 or 2, both Texts will animate.

How can I avoid this problem

Comment: First of all, why do you run your code in the onClick listeners in a separate thread when you then immediately return the execution in mAnimate and mAnimate2 back to the UI thread?

Comment: I edit the Question. The Activity is more complex than this, i wrote only the essential in order to help you to focus on the real problem. It's not about thread wrapping, already tried

Answer (score 0):

Remove new Thread wrap, just call mAnimate() or mAnimate2() in main thread like this:

```
...
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mAnimate();
        }
    });
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           mAnimate2();
        }
    });
...
```

Also mAnimate, mAnimate2 can be optimized like this:

```
private void mAnimate() {
    t.startAnimation(anim_fadeIn);
}



private void mAnimate2() {
    e.startAnimation(anim_fadeIn);
}
```

Comment: No matter how many Threads I wrap the code into. Problem still exist.

Answer (score 0):

What you actually do is you register the same animation to two Views. If you want to only animate one view at the same time you have to clear the Animation for the other View at first otherwise both will start. E.g.

```
private void mAnimate() {
    e.clearAnimation();
    t.startAnimation(anim_fadeIn);
}



private void mAnimate2() {
    t.clearAnimation();
    e.startAnimation(anim_fadeIn);
}
```